# How do I make sure my loop replaces all items of a string that are in given list?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, oop, nested-loops

I've visualised the execution of my code and it works, however as soon as a new match is found, the previous one isn't stored... it only edits the last element of the list that matched a substring.

If I write n-times the same word from the list in the string then they are all modified, but I would like to have all matches replaced.

```
def filter(self,msg):
        self.msg = offensive_msg
        for x in self.keywords:
            for x in self.msg:
                new_template = self.template*len(x)
                clean_msg = offensive_msg.replace(x, new_template[0:len(x)])

            return clean_msg
```

```
def test_multiple_profanities(self):
        f = ProfanityFilter(["duck", "shot", "batch", "mastard"], 'ç%ç*#')
        msg = "abc defghi mastard shot jklduckmno" 
        actual = f.filter(msg)
        expected = "abc defghi ç%ç*#ç ç%ç* jklç%ç*mno"
```

The first one is the function (I haven't yet implemented the condition where a substring would be recognized within another), and then my test suite with my expected & actual.

Very new to programming so I'm hoping someone can help with a solid answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your programs have some issues. This can be done with a simple
stand-alone method such as:

```
def filter(msg,offensive_words,replace_with=""):
    """
    """
    for word in offensive_words:
        msg = msg.replace(word,replace_with)


    return msg

# calling code  
msg  = "I thought I told you to shut your friggin mouth! "
msg += "Please be quiet."
offensive_words = ['friggin','mouth','shut']
replace_with = "***"

fixed = filter(msg=msg,
               offensive_words=offensive_words,
               replace_with=replace_with)

print(fixed)
```

output: I thought I told you to *** your *** ***! Please be quiet.

I hope this helps?

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve it last night, but your method is more straight forward! Appreciate it